# Disable the display or replace contents of a particular div

Tags: html, css

I'm using a SaaS website that generates the following HTML.

```
<div class="sidebar-body">
    <div class="sidebar-block">
      <form class="form-inline subscribe-form">
        ...
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-block">
      .... something else
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-block">
      .... another block
    </div>
</div>
```

Specifically it shows a particular form  (subscribe-form), that I don't want shown. Instead, I want my own form to be shown.

The website allows for custom CSS.

Questions:

1. Is there any way I can disable only the div that contains the subscribe-form but not other divs that have the same class?
2. Would I be able to replace the contents of the div that contains the undesired form?

for now, I have done this:

```
.subscribe-form {
   display: none;
}
```

But it still shows the parent div, which I don't want shown.

Answer (score 2):

You may use jquery parent selectors

```
$('.subscribe-form').parent().css('display','none');
```

[sample](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/stIGo)

Comment: I can only use CSS. I don't believe I can provide this as part of a CSS file.

Comment: currently there is no way in CSS where you can select an element's parent. Unless you specify a class or an ID for that parent and target it. Otherwise, you can only use javascript/jquery.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Is there a way to select the first "sidebar-block" class or is that also not possible?

Comment: Its possible:  .sidebar-block:first-child

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, this can be done using the [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector.

```
.sidebar-body .sidebar-block:nth-child(1) {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Or you can simply use  :first-child instead of nth-child(1)